# Two Warnings: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast and comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

How do I fix both of these warnings. I have decompiled this code and fixed it up a little but I can't get rid of these two warnings.

I guess I need to change `int DecryptedPacketa` to like `char * DecryptedPacketa` or `void * DecryptedPacketa` something like that? or what?

```
encryption.c:26: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
encryption.c:27: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

```
void EncryptPacket(unsigned char *DecryptedPacket)
{
  int DecryptedPacketa;
  char *addressEncryptedPacket;
  const int packetSize = *(unsigned short *)DecryptedPacket+77;  
  unsigned char EncryptedPacket[packetSize];

    *(unsigned short *)(EncryptedPacket+77) = packetSize;
    addressEncryptedPacket = EncryptedPacket + 2;

    //Skips first 2 bytes of DecryptedPacket before looping to end of DecryptedPacket Buffer.
    //Process Byte by Byte for transformations.
    for ( DecryptedPacketa = &DecryptedPacket + 3;            //<- Warning 1
           DecryptedPacketa < &DecryptedPacket + packetSize;  //<- Warning 2
           ++DecryptedPacketa )
    {
      //... Lots of code (fake example below)...
      *addressEncryptedPacket = 123 + *(unsigned char *)DecryptedPacketa; //does encryption here
      //... Lots of code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: um, don't you just mean `for (char *d = DecryptedPacket + 3; d < DecryptedPacket + packetSize; ++d)` ? Why are you putting in an address-of operator?

Comment: BTW this skips 3 bytes but your comment says "skip first 2 bytes".

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Why would you take the address of `DecryptedPacket`, add 3 to the resulting pointer-to-pointer, and store it in an int?

Comment: Oh yeah it starts from 3th byte it does skip 2 as far as I know. I guess it skips 3.. yeah I added those address operator to try to get rid of warnings they didn't exist.. I thinking I have to get the address of the variable and use it from start address to address+packetSize as end. I thought address is same as indexes just bigger numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecryptedPacketa` is of type `int` as defined in the statement

```
int DecryptedPacketa;
```

but you are assigning it a pointer. Again, you are comparing it with a pointer in the loop condition. That's why you are getting those warnings.

What you need to do is define `DecryptedPacketa` to be of type `unsigned char *` and change the `for` loop to

```
unsigned char *DecryptedPacketa;

for (DecryptedPacketa = DecryptedPacket + 2;           
     DecryptedPacketa < DecryptedPacket + packetSize;  
     ++DecryptedPacketa)

{ 
    // loop body
}
```

You need to skip two bytes at the beginning. Therefore, you should start the loop from `DecryptedPacket + 2`. Also, note that the function parameter `DecryptedPacket` is already a pointer. You don't need to apply `address-of` operator `&` to it.

Comment: O i get it.. it's already address. So I must of been getting a address to some unknown location from that address value then right? Sorry I never used C/C++ before

Comment: Wait a second wouldn't that int increase by 4 bytes instead of byte by byte operation? Or that doesn't matter? because I cast it down to byte anyways? or will I lose 3 bytes everytime?

Comment: @user3435580 yes, you are right. Incrementing `DecryptedPacketa` will make it point to the *next element*. It will point to the memory address which is `sizeof(int)` (which is 4 in your case) bytes away from the previous memory location.

Comment: Very odd I have to do more breakpoint debugging here I doubt it does skips of 4 each time in ollydbg memory viewer, since the loop only modifies 1 byte each time afaik. It used to be int originally I don't know how that worked. so I guess like that comment by Matt McNabb is the right solution `char *`.  I think I figured it out.. `int` is `4 bytes` and `char *` is `4 bytes` it couldn't figure out which to use the decompiler.

Comment: @user3435580 You are right. I have updated my answer. Please have a look. Also, you need to start the loop from `DecryptedPacket + 2` to skip the first two bytes. `DecryptedPacket + 3` will skip the first three bytes because `DecryptedPacket + 3` is the address of the 4th element.

Comment: Blah thanks ajay I just got confused it does already skip +2 (3 bytes) before the loop begins then it starts from the +3 (4 bytes) I guess. Either way I'll figure this out with no problem by just debugging it line by line. Thanks for everything. I think I should convert it to use array box's [2] [3] haha, those make my brain wrap this stuff easier.

Comment: @user3435580 yes, using array subscript operator `[]` makes code clearer and more readable. I suggest using it.

Comment: Tricky the errors came back when I did `DecryptedPacket[2]` instead of `DecryptedPacket + 2` but now I used the `&` sign again and errors disappeared lol like so `&DecryptedPacket[2]` I guess in array mode it's no longer a address but in fact the value stored so I need to make it back to address sooo can't just change + 2 to [2] lol without using the & sign.

Comment: `DecryptedPacket[2]` is the value at the memory address you want. You have to apply `&` operator to it as you were earlier.